# How to remove an item from an array?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have this

```
<span @click="remove(product)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span> element, It triggers this function:<br/>

remove(product) {
  this.form.products.$remove(product);
} <br/>
```

But it outputs this error:`TypeError: this.form.products.$remove is not a function` i don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `splice` method to remove the item from an array

First get the index of the item

```
let index = this.form.products.indexOf(product);
```

Then remove it using `splice`

```
this.form.products.splice(index,1);
```